# Reversing a string in a recursive way

Tags: pascal

I want to reverse a string using a recursive function, here is my code:

```
Program InvertTheString;
var n:integer;word:string;

Function Invert (N:integer; word:string) : string;
begin
     if N=1 then
        Invert:=word[N]+Invert
     Else
        Invert:=Invert(N-1,word);
end;

BEGIN
readln(word);
n:=length(word);
writeln (Invert(N,word));

writeln;write('Press Enter To Exit...');
readln;
END.
```

But it is not working, where is worng?

Comment: yeah, compiled, but output is so horrible !!!

Comment: How does the output look like then? Maybe add it to your question...

Comment: for example think input is "abc", then the output should be "cba" but it is "^$%#$^%$&%#$%@#$#@%$^$#%#$@%@$%@$%" or something like this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Function Invert (N:integer; word:string) : string;
begin
     if N=0 then
        Invert:=''
     Else
        Invert:= word[N] + Invert(N-1,word);
end;
```

Comment: Nice and Accepted, THank you very much rene.

Answer (score 2):

I don't do Pascal, but a typical (simple) recursive reverse, in pseudo-code, looks like:

```
function reverse(word)
  if empty(word) return ""
  else return reverse(withoutFirstLetter(word)) + firstLetterOf(word)
```

Comment: But I need the pascal one, really I can write it for C++, but in pascal there are some differences..

Answer (score 0):

```
Function Invert (ch:string) : string;
begin
 if ch='' then
 Invert:=''
 else
 {get the last letter of the string + eliminate it and execute the function}
 Invert:=copy(ch,length(ch),1)+Invert(copy(ch,1,length(ch)-1));
end;
```

Comment: Your formatting seems to be incorrect - indent lines with four spaces to format them as code. Also, can you explain your code?

Comment: if you have pascal compiler you can try it. the idea is just reversing a string recursively with just one parameter. the complexity of this function still greater than the other one so it's not a solution but just for apparenc